# How to access environment variables in boost unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, boost, environment-variables

How can I access the environment variables from the test cases in the boost unit test?

I tried to use getenv within a test case but I failed to get the value of the variable I exported !!

Actually I use linux and run the unit test from a shell script like this:

`#!/bin/bash
 export x=x 
 ./run_unit_test`

Answer (score 1):

You clearly didn't export it in a parent process of the unit test runner.

E.g. it wouldn't work to be in an editor, like Vim, and say

```
 :!export q=q
 :!./test
```

Because the export is in a subshell, but the tests run in a separate process, which is not a child of the subshell that exports `q`.

Instead, what *would* work is

```
!export q=q; ./test
```

Of course if you don't use vim, you will have different commands, but the same principles apply: environments are inherited. One usual approach is to set the variable in the environment even before launching your IDE (so it doesn't matter whether you use Visual Studio or, indeed, Vim).

When you change the environment (e.g. on windows), be sure to restart that IDE so it can pick up the modified environment.

Comment: Actually I use linux and run the unit test from a shell script like this:
"#!/bin/bash
export x=x
./run_unit_test"

Comment: @Rod add relevant information to the question. Comments don't do a good job here anyways

Answer (score 0):

I have found that no problem in reading the environment variables within the boost test cases.

It was my fault as I set the environment variables then ran the test case using sudo :'(

So the new environment did not have the exported variables.